# C# Use of un-assigned variable

Tags: c#

Hmmmm, I wonder why isn't this working...It gives an error stating "Use of unassigned local variable max". So, what is wrong with this code? I cant figure it out.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public int CalculateHighestNum(int value1, int value2, int value3) 
        {
            int max;

            if (value1 > (value2 & value3))
            {
                max = value1;
            }
            else if(value2 > (value1 & value3))
            {
                max = value2;
            }
            else if(value3 > (value1 & value2)) 
            {
                max = value3;
            }

            return max;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            Console.Write("Enter first NUM : ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter second NUM : ");
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter third NUM : ");
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Program p = new Program();
            int highestnum = p.CalculateHighestNum(a, b, c);

            Console.WriteLine(highestnum + " = Highest Number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this does what you think it does? `if (value1 > (value2 & value3))` - might make sense in English...

Comment: Try this for your requirement:

    int max = Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c));

Try to explore simpler ways.

Comment: John3136, I think that checks whether value1 is greater than value 2 and value3

Comment: @user3497152 no it doesn't. it performs _bitwise and_ operation between value2 and value3 then it checks if value1 is higher than the result of the AND operation.

Comment: If you want to persist with this logic, try if((value1 > value2) && (value1 > value3)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set an initial value to `max`, or any other local variable, before you can use it.

```
int max = 0;
```

The reason for this is to reduce the chance of using a variable without assigning it a sensible default, and because the variable needs to be assigned to something before being returned. (In this case, if your `if` statements are all false)

The compiler will not show this error if you assign a value to the variable in all cases, such as in an `else` statement.

Also, as @Partha explained in the comments, you could simplify your logic to just:

```
return Math.Max(value1, Math.Max(value2, value3));
```

Comment: To clarify a bit, theoretically, your `if/else` statements might not hit, so then you would `return max` where `max` is not initialized

Comment: It will compile, but return wrong max value. Actually it might be good to keep `max` initially uninitialized in such cases.

Comment: Added your advice @GrantWinney

Comment: for variety, here is another alternative `return new[] { value1, value2, value3 }.Max();`

Comment: @GrantWinney Absolutely. I meant that if we know that one of `if - else` branches must initialize `max`, then we may intentionally skip `int max = 0`. So if by mistake we do not cover all cases, we get the compilation error. And compilation error is much better than a function which compiles, but misbehaves by returning `0` in some cases.